# How do I use autocomplete on a login generated by JavaScript? It doesn't use forms

Tags: javascript, email, autocomplete

It actually sends the login credentials through a websocket. The entire website is generated by JavaScript. How do I have the browser suggesting a username on the username field? There's no forms in this website but the input's are used as text fields.

tried all sorts of things element.autocomplete property as "on" and "email", element.type="email" element.id="email". Nothing seems to trigger the browser to suggest emails.

Comment: https://web.dev/sign-in-form-best-practices/ create pseudo forms, add meaningful names to inputs, simulate navigation on successful login using browser history API